# Android ADT not detecting device in Windows XP-64 bit

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am trying to install and develop an application in android, for that I just downloaded the latest "adt-bundle-windows-x86_64" and un-zip it.

Eclipse and all are working but it didn't recognizing the android device ( Samsung Galaxy SL ).

I downloaded the 32 bit version and tested the same device in that machine. Its working fine.

I google a lot and did many things like enable USB debug and all.. Installed Kies, Updated the kies also.

Some one please help

Comment: Check if `Google USB driver` is installed with `SDK Manager`

Comment: Does KIES work? If yes, try adding the VENDOR_ID in the adb_usb.ini

Comment: yes KIES working perfectly ... how to add VENDOR_ID ?

Comment: yes Google USB driver is installed

Comment: @323go there is no such a file in c:/Documents and Settings/username/.android/adb_usb.ini

Comment: If you don't have the adb_usb.ini in your .android folder, there's a good chance you don't have the google USB drivers installed. They're in sdk\extras\google\usb_drivers. Check the USB device in Device Manager, find the vendor_id, and place it in adb_usb.ini with the hex-prefix `0x`, like so: 0x1949. Lastly, `adb kill-server` then `adb devices`. Good luck.